# Jetty '{servlet}/{parameter}' url routing

Tags: java, url, dictionary, routes, jetty

I'm using jetty 9.0.3.

How to map an URL such as www.myweb.com/{servlet}/{parameter} to the given servlet and parameter?

For example, the URL '/client/12312' will route to clientServlet and its `doGet` method will receive 12312 as a parameter.

Comment: You'll need to use a filter to extract parts of the url.

Comment: Using patterns in web.xml or in the servlet? any example?

Comment: I don't have an example. In web.xml, you can map `/client/*`. For the `12312`, you'll need to extract it from the path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll have 2 parts to worry about.

1. The pathSpec in your `WEB-INF/web.xml`
2. The [HttpServletRequest.getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) in your servlet.

#### The pathSpec

In your `WEB-INF/web.xml` you have to declare your Servlet and your url-patterns (also known as the pathSpec).

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app 
   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
   metadata-complete="false"
   version="3.0"> 

  <display-name>Example WebApp</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>clientServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.mycompany.ClientServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>clientServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/client/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This sets up the servlet implemented as class `com.mycompany.ClientServlet` on the name `clientServlet` then specifies the url-pattern of `/client/*` for incoming request URLs.

The extra `/*` at the end of the url-pattern allows any incoming pattern that starts with `/client/` to be accepted, this is important for the pathInfo portion.

#### The pathInfo

Next we get into our Servlet implementation.

In your [doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServlet.html#doGet%28javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse%29) implementation on ClientServlet you should access the [req.getPathInfo()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29) value, which will receive the portion of the request URL that is after the `/client` on your url-pattern.

Example:

```
Request URL        Path Info
----------------   ------------
/client/           /
/client/hi         /hi
/client/world/     /world/
/client/a/b/c      /a/b/c
```

At this point you do whatever logic you want to against the information from the Path Info

Comment: Thanks! I did something similar but in the servlet I used 'req.getRequestURI().split("/(.*?)")[2];' instead to filter the uri string. I will implement 'getPathInfo()' which it's far more cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Jersey` and register the following class in the `ResourceConfig` packages, which is handling `../worker/1234` url patterns.

read more: [When to use @QueryParam vs @PathParam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam)

```
@Path("v1/services/{entity}")
@GET
public class RequestHandler(@PathParam("entity")String entity, @PathParam("id")String id){
   @path({id})
   public Entity handle(){

   }
}
```