# Does Jetty provide annotations for mapping URLs to methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, jetty

I want to map several methods to different URLs in a single servlet.
The only I can find is what's described at [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965162/jetty-servlet-parameter-url-routing)

This seems a little too much work when other frameworks like Spring provide method annotations to map URLs to the methods.

But I want to keep my application free of such frameworks.

Is it possible to make use of any such 'annotation' mechanism without using complex frameworks like Spring or CXF?

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at resteasy, which is an jax-rs implementation. Indeed it's a framework, but much lighter than Spring, and only designed to deal with annotation based rest services.

```
Example:
    @Path("/test")
    public class Endpoint {
    @GET
        @Produces("application/json")
        public Response listAll(@QueryParam("start") Integer startPosition, @QueryParam("max") Integer maxResult) {

           // all your code goes here

           return Response.ok().build();

        }
    }
```

Setting up RestEasy is as easy as creating a class like this:

```
@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class RestApplication extends Application {
}
```

Whereas the rest url is at localhost/{appname}/rest/test

Simply add resteasy maven dependency with:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
    <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Resteasy docs:

http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.9.Final/userguide/html/index.html