# Remove Html Extension On Jetty

Tags: java, jetty, embedded-jetty

I would like to be able to go to

`https://localhost:8080/users/pages/profile` (without the Server failing) instead of `https://localhost:8080/users/pages/profile.html`

So I tried

```
ServletContextHandler pagesContext = new ServletContextHandler();
pagesContext.setContextPath("/users/pages");
ResourceHandler resourceHandler = new ResourceHandler();
resourceHandler.setResourceBase("./src/main/webapp/pages");
resourceHandler.setDirectoriesListed(true);
pagesContext.setHandler(resourceHandler);
pagesContext.addServlet(new ServletHolder("default", DefaultServlet.class), "*.html"); 
// TODO this is not working currently
jettyServer.addHandler(pagesContext);
```

But it isn't working!
It complains that `profile` page doesn't exist but `profile.html` works fine

Comment: That is not supported by Jetty (or any servlet Java web server for that matter).  Any implementation of this support would be highly webapp specific with rules specific to that webapp.  The lookup requirements would either need some complex caching (for performance), or frequent filesystem requests (simplifying the implementation, and reducing performance in a non-trivial way)

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt since you are a Jetty dev, could you please tell me how to route http requests to https? for example, if the user goes to `http://domain.com` then quickly redirect him to `https://domain.com`

Comment: Use [`SecureRedirectHandler`](http://download.eclipse.org/jetty/9.3.11.v20160721/apidocs/org/eclipse/jetty/server/handler/SecuredRedirectHandler.html) - *Tip: be sure you have your HttpConfiguration properly setup.*

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by url routing. Here is similar question, in which has been explained, how to do it: [Jetty '{servlet}/{parameter}' url routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16965162/jetty-servlet-parameter-url-routing)

In nutshell you will only define new servlet. (without or with parameter)

Comment: I'm using Jersey so I can do that url routing. but how can I do that with static pages?!

Comment: Make dynamic page from static page...there will be no result difference...

Comment: so you're suggesting I do something like

`@Path("users/pages/profile")
 @Produces("text/html")
  public Response getProfilePage() {
    // ???
  }`

Comment: but what `Response` should I return? I want to load the written html page in my webapp folder. How can I do that?

Comment: You can load that HTML into it. See Hello World example: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty /by the way I am unhappy you haven't given bounty to anyone/

Comment: oh lol. well your solution was not well elaborate! And I was busy I didn't check SO all this time

Comment: I actually still don't get your solution; are you suggesting that I write something like this? `response.getWriter().println("<h1>hello world<h1>");` which is a very horrible idea!

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, there won't be src folder anymore after packaging the application, In eclipse usually it will all source files will be compiled and moved to classes or build folder, so changing the path from **./src/main/webapp/pages** to the correct one may help fixing your issue.

Comment: currently. that is not my problem! but I will fix that

Answer (score 0):

Jetty wont handle such exception. its entirely upto servlet to do handle such url mapping. Why dont you look at Spring web mvc that will make things a lot more easier to do what you have been asking.

Here's a good [place](http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/) to get started
[Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: I know about Spring but I simply cannot use it in this project! I thought Jetty handles such url mapping