# How to receive the input parameters in REST Service call?

Tags: java, ajax, rest

I am performing an AJAX request this way

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://hosti[:8080/OrderSnacks/oms/toppings?topping=' + id_attr_val,
            jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
            cache: true,
            dataType: 'jsonp',

            jsonp: false,
            success: function (response) {
             console.log(response);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                $("#divResult").html("WebSerivce unreachable");
            }
        });
});
```

Inside my REST service call , i am unable to receive this parameter

```
@Path("/toppings")
public class ToppingService {
    @GET
    @Consumes("application/text")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public String getData(@PathParam("toppingid") String toppingid) {
        return "";
    }
```

I have tried all the options that is

```
public String getData(@QueryParam("toppingid") String toppingid) {
}

public String getData(@PathParam("toppingid") String toppingid) {

}
```

But nothing is working .

Could you please tell me how to receive those parameters ??

Answer (score 2):

You have a problem : you send *topping* but you ask for *toppingid*.

Comment: Thanks for this ,  should i use QueryParam or PathParam

Comment: In your case, PathParam. See the difference : http://stackoverflow.com/a/11569077/1392463