# Pass an URL as param in RESTful WebServices

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I'm defining a **RESTful** WebService in **Java**.

It takes as input:

- an *username* (for instance, `jdoe`);
- an *URL* (for instance: `https://blablablabla.io/sample?boh=mah`).

By using **GET** method of the **HTTP protocol**, it should produce a `JSON` file.

Which is the best way to pass these params?

In this particular case, is there a best practice to follow in order to properly pass an URL as param?

Comment: FYI: Have a look at Dropwizard, you have a simple REST Framework including Jetty and other useful stuff. Easy to use and you have a good description how to start -> http://dropwizard.io/getting-started.html

Comment: I'm yet using RESTEasy on JBoss.

Answer (score 3):

You must first encode it, you can use

```
URLEncoder.encode("url");
```

Comment: And then, should I pass it as QueryParam?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define an http `GET` method, then the only way to pass parameters to it is through the URI query string (ie. `?x=y&...`).

This is because `GET` calls can not take in a message body.

If you want to pass in more complicated information, you will need to use `POST`, `PUT`, or some other method. Though, if you are actually just *getting* information (semantically), then you shouldn't use anything but `GET`.

Comment: Thus, should I pass the URL as queryparam or pathparam?

Comment: @vdenotaris "I'd recommend putting any required parameters in the path, and any optional parameters should almost certainly be query string parameters." See: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11569077/2479481)

Answer (score -1):

Also you can use Path parameters

This is example

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserResorce {

      @GET
      @Path("/{username}")
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      public String getUser(@PathParam("username") String username)){

      }
}


The url is http://domain_name/your_application_path/users/username
```