# How to define and test a DELETE operation endpoint using @QueryParam with Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-test-framework

Can I use `@QueryParam` when defining a DELETE operation? If yes, when I need to test it using jersey client, how the java code will look like? I tried something like

```
String result = client.target(url)
                      .queryParam("id",3)
                      .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                      .delete(String.class);
```

But it was not working.

Comment: It would be better design to have the id in the path, ie. `DELETE /url/:id` and use `@PathParam`. If you can change it, I suggest you do.

Comment: @Bentaye Ok. So when we need to use QueryParam?

Comment: This is a whole new question regarding RESTapi design , I recommend you simply google it you will find a lot of answers. this for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a `DELETE` endpoint using either `@PathParam` (recommended) or `@QueryParam`

**With @PathParam** (recommended)

Endpoint: `url/:id`

```
@DELETE
@Path("{id}")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void deletePathParam(@PathParam("id") int id) {
  ...
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testDeletePathParam() {
  Response output = target(url+"/3").request().delete();
   // asserts
}
```

**With @QueryParam** (bad RESTapi design)

Endpoint: `url?id=:id`

```
@DELETE
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void deleteQueryParam(@QueryParam("id") int id) {
  ...
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
public void testDeleteQueryParam() {
  Response output = target(url).queryParam("id", 3).request().delete();
   // asserts
}
```