# Why use "?" instead of ":" in URL?

Tags: url, url-design

We can use

```
'PATCH /companies/:id' : 'CompanyController.find'
```

to update data.

One suggested me that I can use the alternative way:

```
'PATCH /companies/find?key=Value'
```

But I do not know what it works. Please explain me why we prefer `?` mark than `:` mark in search path.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11569077

Comment: Does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50925157/1426227) works for you? Feedback is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either or. The biggest reason most people chose one or the other is just how they want to present the URL to the user.

Using a path variable (`:`) can symbolize you're accessing a defined resource, like a user ID, where as an argument (`?`) can symbolize you're are dynamically changing/searching something within a defined resource, like a token or search term.

From what I can tell that's the general practice I see:

```
example.com/user/:username
```

versus

```
example.com/user/?search="foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

If we are firing GET request, ? symbol is used to let the server know  the url parameter variables starts from there. And this is commonly used. I didn't used : symbol instead of ?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably messing the things up:

- According to your example, `:id` indicates a variable that must me replaced by an actual value in some frameworks such as Express. See the [documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) for details.
- And `?` indicates the beginning of the [query string](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) component according to the [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).

Comment: yeah, I apologize that i cannot vote for you guys because I don't have enough reputation points.

Answer (score -2):

<s>It's a rule to design rest api

you can find 'how to design a rest api'</s>

Assuming below code is Sails.js

```
'PATCH /companies/:id' : 'CompanyController.find'
```

It will makes REST API that be mapped onto 'CompanyController.find' by using PathParam. Like this

```
www.example.com/companies/100
```

Second one will makes REST API by using QueryParam.
It also be mapped onto 'CompanyController.find'

```
/companies/find?key=Value
```

But the API format is different. Like this

```
www.example.com/companies/find?key=100
```

PathParam or QueryParam is fine to make REST API. 
If the Key is primary for company entity,
I think PathParam is more proper than QueryParam.