# Sending POST request with POSTMAN to Java REST API and getting null values in the xml response

Tags: java, xml, rest, api, postman

I am creating a REST Service in Java and now I am building the post method which has 2 parameters that has to be inputted as xml in postman (for test) and get a response as xml in java and insert it in database.

For starters I am trying to add the values as Query Params in POSTMAN with key and value. The response is 200 but the xml is CUI=null Mesaj=null

Both values are null even though I added values for both keys in Postman.

How can it see the values? This is the java code:

```
@Stateless
@Path("/cererepost")
public class HelloWorldResource {
    Resp x = new Resp();
    @EJB
    private NameStorageBean nameStorage;
    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of    helloworld.HelloWorldResource
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @POST
    @Produces("application/xml")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response postMsg(@PathParam("cui") String cui,    @PathParam("mesaj") String mesaj)  {
      
        String xmlString = "CUI=" + cui + " Mesaj=" + mesaj;
        Response response = Response.status(200).type(MediaType.TEXT_XML).entity(xmlString).build();
        return response;
    }
}
```

What should I modify so I can see the parameter values that I send in the post in the xml that postman is generating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@PathParam("cui") String cui`
this line shows that values from client side should be passed as path parameters, not query string, something like this:

correct:
`/cererepost/some_value`

If you want to get them as query string params in server side, change `@PathParam("cui")` to `@QueryParam("cui")`.

For understading the differences between `query string` and `path variables` take alook at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam).

Answer (score 0):

in the postman you  might miss typed the variables name. It might doesn't much with table that you created using java

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).