# How to send delete request to the server from android studio?

Tags: android, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, httprequest, http-delete

I am trying to make an e-commerce mobile application and the backend for that is built in Spring boot with JPA. now I need to send a delete request to my server from the app. I can't use the primary key for that purpose. I need to delete them by name or email.

the normal delete URL for delete request will look something like this

```
https:localhost:8080/api/customers/1
```

but in my case, I need to delete the customers based on the email not by id
my Jpa code looks like this

```
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Integer> {

@Transactional
@RestResource(exported = true)
List<Customer> deleteByEmail(String email);

// the url will look something like this: http://localhost:8080/api/customers/search/findByEmail?customer_email=thekopsfc.sd@gmail.com
Customer findByEmail(@Param("customer_email") String email);

}
```

how could I send a delete request to the server?

Comment: Can you find customer by email?

Comment: @MxWild yes... i used same for delete but it doesn't seem to work.. i would gladly provide additional code if you can help.. 

the request url looked like this
            http://localhost:8080/api/customer/search/findByEmail?email=helloworld@gmail.com

Comment: Can you share the code for findByEmail? And how you make call to it?

Comment: @miyavmiyav i have edited the question please do check

Comment: On the backed you does have a controller with @DeleteMapping("customers/{email}") {service.deleteByEmail(email);} And than you can get this url.

Comment: See your findByEmail methodhas \@Param annotation so that it checks for value after ?customer_email= 
Other way to use it you can use path params like the comment above here are some examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11552248/when-to-use-queryparam-vs-pathparam

Also another way is \@RequestBody but DELETE doesnt use that

your delete method doesnt provide anything like that unless I'm not completelty sure what \@RestResource annotation does (not using springboot that much

Answer (score 0):

check this [building-user-authentication-android](https://rahulrockin.medium.com/building-user-authentication-android-application-using-android-studio-and-spring-boot-backend-480676f858e) using retrofit2.

In you controller:

```
@Autowired
private CustomerRepository customerRepository;

@RequestMapping(value = "/api/customers/delete", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public List<Customer> deleteByEmail(@RequestBody String email){
        return customerRepository.deleteByEmail(email);
    }
```

In your android apllication:

build.gradle

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

add Network.java:

```
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.logging.HttpLoggingInterceptor;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;

public class Network {

    private static HttpLoggingInterceptor httpLoggingInterceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

    public static Retrofit getInstance() {
        Retrofit.Builder builder = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://192.168.43.126:8080/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(httpLoggingInterceptor).build());
        return builder.build();

    }
}
```

your interface ApiService.java

```
import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Body;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.POST;
import retrofit2.http.PUT;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface ApiService {

    @POST("//api/customers/delete")
    Call<Customer> deleteByEmail(@Body Customer customer);

}
```